# PHP calling 'unknown' methods with parameters

Tags: php

Im trying to build routing script in php.

Its currently working but now i want to add parameters and this is where im stuck.

Code im currently using:

$controllerName is the name of the class.
$action is the name of the method going to be called.

```
$controllerClass = new $controllername();
$controllerClass->$action();
```

The parameters i want parse into the method are in a array.

My problem is that in the method being called make references to (public) variables inside the object so if i use:

```
call_user_func_array()
```

im getting errors: `Using $this when not in object context`

Somebody got a good idea to solve this?

EDIT: Found my problem, when i was using the call_user_func_array() i was giving the class name as parameter rather than an object. That was why it was not in object mode but static mode.

Comment: how you are calling call_user_func_array() in your code ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty call_user_func_array(array($classname, $action), $methodparams); but that ofcourse should be the instance of the class rather then the classname.... thx

Comment: are u sure $action is returning a string as method_name and the same is defined in the class ?

Comment: yes i am but i fixed the error in call_user_func_array() i gave the name of the class instead of an object of the class so that was why it  was in static context and not in object context.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$this` somewhere that is not within a class definition. `$this` should only be used within a class.

Comment: i fixed the error in call_user_func_array() i gave the name of the class instead of an object of the class so that was why it was in static context and not in object context

Comment: @user1971401 please post updated code with fix if there is still an issue.